# Why isn't Chef reloading my Nginx & Tomcat file properly?

Tags: tomcat, nginx, chef-infra

I'm using Chef, Tomcat & Nginx to configure my front end machines, using a .war file in the Tomcat root that expands when it's been placed in there and accessed for the first time. Here's my recipe:

```
include_recipe 'selinux::disabled'

%w{curl zip unzip tomcat7 lynx mysql-client}.each do |pkg|
  package pkg do
    action :install
  end
end

package 'nginx' do
  action :install
end

service 'tomcat7' do
  service_name 'tomcat7'
  supports :restart => true, :status => true
  action [:start, :enable]
end

service 'nginx' do
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end

cookbook_file "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" do
  source "index.html"
  mode "0644"
end

execute "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1" do
  only_if "getsebool -a | grep 'httpd_can_network_connect --> off'"
end

user 'nginx' do
  comment 'nginx user'
  system true
  shell '/bin/false'
end

template "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" do
  source "nginx.conf.erb"
  mode '0644'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  notifies :reload, 'service[nginx]', :delayed
end

[ bunch of stuff copying the .war file in ]

service 'tomcat7' do
  action :restart
end


execute "reload nginx" do
  command "nginx -s reload"
  action :nothing
end
```

And it works fine. It even reloads nginx at the end properly - here's the end of the run:

```
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com   * service[tomcat7] action restart
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     - restart service service[tomcat7]
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com   * service[nginx] action reload
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     - reload service service[nginx]
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com   * service[nginx] action reload
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     - reload service service[nginx]
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com Running handlers:
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com Running handlers complete
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com Chef Client finished, 17/25 resources updated in 171.195633435 seconds
```

Everything is set, but when I load the page, and I get the default nginx page, as though nginx is not picking up the configuration file properly. The file is definitely there, and well formatted. I go and execute:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

And it works fine. Then, when I finally have looked for everything and it all looks right, all I do is the following:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

And all works properly. This leads me to believe Chef is not doing something properly when it comes to reloading nginx, but I can't for the life of me figure out what that is.

**UPDATE**

Per SlayedByLucifer's suggestion, I now end the recipe by reloading using a command, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: the `reload` action in `service` resource is not quite equivalent to `nginx -s reload`. When testing manually, do not run `nginx -s reload` and try reloading using `service nginx reload` command. If you still face the same issue, then this is not the chef issue. But if it resolves the issue, then you should file a chef bug.

Comment: Hmph... i'm stumped. I've now updated the above to include the command inline, and it still doesn't work. Do I have to delay running it or something?

Comment: Using `nginx -s reload` shouldn't be necessary. What distro are you using? Post the chef log so we know what's happening

Comment: Can you say more about posting the log? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I posted what the output is above.

Comment: Hi dear, any progress? I have the same problem on ubuntu 14.04 and nginx

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Might come of a configuration issue in the nginx config, like providing wrong `listen` directives.

Longer answer;
I struggled with the same, and it turns out the problem for me was a mis-configuration in my nginx configuration. The weird thing was that it reloaded just fine when I did it manually with `service reload nginx` from the shell on the server. Executing the same would not work through chef.

The reason it did not work in my case became apparent when I also tried to schedule a restart of nginx from Chef which would start throwing errors like `[::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)`.
I solved it by replacing my `listen 80; listen [::]:80;` with only `listen      [::]:80;`.

See the following article for a more in-depth answer: https://chrisjean.com/fix-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use/